# Capistrano: Before deploy:published hook needs to know release directory

Tags: composer-php, capistrano

I am making a task that runs the slow `composer install` command BEFORE the `current` symlink is changed to point to the new release (because I don't want my new release to be broken for the first minute of it's life while the packaged are fetched).

```
before 'deploy:publishing', :composartisan do
    on roles(:app) do
        within fetch(:latest_release_directory) do
            execute "cd #{current_path} && composer dump-autoload && composer install && php artisan storage:link && php artisan migrate"
        end
    end
end
```

This doesn't work because `fetch(:latest_release_directory)` returns the current release, not the one that we are building and about to published in a few minutes time.

**How can I fetch the folder path of the release we are building?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself. I needed to change 2 lines:

- `within fetch(:latest_release_directory)` became `within release_path`
- `cd #{current_path}` became `cd #{release_path}`

Here's the full working snippet...

```
before 'deploy:publishing', :composartisan do
    on roles(:app) do
        within release_path do
            execute "cd #{release_path} && composer dump-autoload && composer install && php artisan storage:link && php artisan migrate"
        end
    end
end
```

*Bit of a rant, but why is this not really documented on the Capistrano site? I found my solution by chance while browsing other Capistrano questions on StackOverflow. Now I look back I see `release_path` is only mentioned once in the **deploy:reverting** section of the rollbacks page* (http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/rollbacks/#deployreverting). A page that lists and explains all the variables that are made available seems like a basic essential to me.

*[Not to be a back-seat-driver who bitches at open source, I will endeavour to fork the documentation and fix it myself when I feel my Capistrano skills are ninja enough to reliably write about it.]*

*</rant>*